# jQuery Animation Works But Not Always

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that contains an `input` with `type="image"` attribute. I am changing the image everytime whether I get a success or fail call.

But It doesn't work always, I don't see why. Is there any possible way to eliminate `setTimeout(function())` or alternative way to implement this animation since this may cause the problem?

**HTML**

```
<p class="text-center" style="color:brown" id="input_result">Send</p>
<form data-ajax="false" method="post" name="login_form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="image" src="images/default.png" class="img-responsive center-block" name="submit" class="submitBtn" id="input_img">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/sendmail.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data, status, xhttp) {

                $("#input_img").slideUp(2000).slideDown(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Success animation
                    $('#input_img').attr("src", "images/success.png");
                    jQuery("input[type='image']").prop("disabled", true);
                    $('selector').click(false);
                    $("#input_result").text("Sent!");
                    $("#input_result").css("color", "green");
                }, 1999);
                this.submit();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                $("#input_img").slideUp(2000).slideDown(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Fail animation
                    $('#input_img').attr("src", "images/fail.png");
                    jQuery("input[type='image']").prop("disabled", true);
                    $('selector').click(false);
                    $("#input_result").text("Failed to send!");
                    $("#input_result").css("color", "red");
                }, 1999);
            },
        });
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Input tag doesn't support `src` attribute, you should use `value` instead. You can alternatively place an image tag and show your input's value every time it changes.

Comment: @FaridRn Thank you, I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form using `this.submit();` the page is submitted to the server and reloaded again, so you lose the success animation. Since you are posting the values in the function, you don't need to submit the form.

Comment: also a "e.preventDefault()" is in order, because the function is bind to the "submit" event, so the form submits anyways the normal way

Comment: I have tried both with `this.submit()` or without. It does not effect the current problem. I am able to trigger this issue with 25:1 ratio. But I don't need `this.submit();` at all as far as I understand.

Comment: is your page reloading?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky No, just updating the `input` image and `<p>` object provided above with the provided script.

Comment: some more troubleshooting - which part doesn't always work, slideUp or slideDown (I guess the second)

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Yes, only the second one. Instead of animation, it waits desired second then instantly pops up

Comment: if it executes the event than the code works (slideUp/hide -> change data -> slideDown/show without reloading the page) and try with slideDown(2000) - maybe it's just too fast

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Thank you for suggestion, but unluckily the problem still occurs. I should better check built-in open source animations instead of using mine own. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("#input_img").slideUp(2000).slideDown(1000);` you can use the callback of slideUp to run your function and then in the end of that function call `.slideDown()` 
Like:
`$("#input_img").slideUp(2000, function(){
       $('#input_img').attr("src", "images/fail.png");
        jQuery("input[type='image']").prop("disabled", true);
        $('selector').click(false);
        $("#input_result").text("Failed to send!");
        $("#input_result").css("color", "red");
        $("#input_img").slideDown(1000);
}`

Comment: I am still facing with the same issue after updating code like to this.